# How do I pass arguments to docker run in a CLI (Command Line Interface)?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I need my image to start with this command:

```
docker run -it --rm --security-opt seccomp=./chrome.json <image_id>
```

I'm deploying it to Google Compute Engine: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers

As far as I understand, I can't specify arguments there, so Google Cloud starts it with just `docker run` command.

How do I pass these arguments? Maybe I can specify those args in Dockerfile somehow?

Comment: Have you deployed your GCE instance based on container-optimized OS? If yes, Seems  that you can run docker in same way as usual. Refer here -> https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/run-container-instance

Comment: @kallusis369 i'm deploying images using this command: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/instances/update-container

I don't understand how to tie it with the instruction you've referred to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the feature to deploy container directly on Compute Engine, you are limited to the definition of

- Entry point
- Args to pass at the entry point
- Environment variables

That's all, you can't add additional/custom params.

One solution is, instead of using the built in feature, to use the [container-optimized OS (COS) on your Compute Engine and to create a startup script](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/how-to/run-container-instance) to download and run the container with the docker args that you want

```
METADATA=http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1
SVC_ACCT=$METADATA/instance/service-accounts/default
ACCESS_TOKEN=$(curl -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google' $SVC_ACCT/token | cut -d'"' -f 4)
docker login -u oauth2accesstoken -p $ACCESS_TOKEN https://gcr.io
docker run … gcr.io/your-project/your-image
```

On the latest line, you can customize the run param in your startup script.

So now, for the update, you have to update the startup script and to reset your VM (or to create a new Compute Engine with COS and the new startup script; and to delete the previous one).

It's matter of tradeoff between the convenience of a built in feature and the customization capacity.

Comment: okay, all this makes total sense. I'm trying to go startup-script way. I've been using `startup-script` metadata a lot before, but not with containers. But right now it just doesn't work. I can run it manually, it works absolutely fine. But on instance start there is no trace of it running in logs for some reason. It's present in the instance metadata, it starts with `#!/bin/bash` and it's certainly not misspelled.

Comment: On the latest Docker version, I needed to change the 4th line to `echo $ACCESS_TOKEN | sudo docker login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://gcr.io` for this to work. Also [make sure](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles) your Compute Engine service account has the "Storage Object Viewer" role.