# In Google Cloud VMs, Is it possible to override container port mappings in instance details page?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Google Cloud VM allows you to easily deploy container image. In the web console, I am able to override `Command`, `Command Arguments`, and `Environment Variables` for container deployment. as shown below.

[image]

`Command` will override default `Entrypoint` value set in Dockerfile, while `Command arguments` will provide additional parameters for the entry-point.

I was wondering if it is possible to configure port mappings for the container.

For instance, when you launch a container using docker cli, you can specify which one of the host ports maps to the container port.

`docker run -p 3000:8080 container/name`

`docker run -p 9000:8080 container/name`

Similarly, can port mappings be set in the VM instance details page? I tried by writing `-p 80:8080` in `Command Arguments` but that seems to end up supplying argument value to the container like below, which has different effect.

`docker run container/name -p 9000:8080`

Comment: Does my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65388567/how-do-i-pass-arguments-to-docker-run-in-a-cli-command-line-interface/65392740#65392740) help you to solve your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Google document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/deploying-containers#limitations),GCE doesn't support port mapping like docker's -p option.

> You can't map a VM instance's ports to the container's ports (Docker's
> -p option). To enable access to your containers, see Publishing container ports.

In GCP instance, Container ports can only have a one-to-one mapping to the host vm ports.

To get more detailed information about publishing container ports, refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers#publishing_container_ports).

Or You can use [App Engine flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible) environment with a custom runtime instead.

It is more suitable for running containers on GCE.